# How to make pdf outlines work correctly in LuaTeX?

Tags: pdf, luatex, plain-tex, bookmarks, cweb

cwebmac.tex version 3.67 --- July 2006

The following Lua code converts string from UTF-8 to UTF-16BE with `tex.write`, which prints all with catcode 12, except space, which is what is needed. We add the code to the top of `cwebmac.tex`:

```
% from navigator.tex
\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
  local function to8 (...)
    local arg, str = {...}, ""
    for i, num in ipairs(arg) do
      tex.write(string.char(92) .. string.format("%03o", num))
    end
  end
  function toutf16(str)
    tex.write(string.char(92) .. "376" .. string.char(92) .. "377")
    for c in string.utfvalues(str) do
      if c < 0x10000 then
        to8(c / 256, c % 256)
      else
        c = c - 0x10000
        local a, b = c / 1024 + 0xD800, c % 1024 + 0xDC00
        to8(a / 256, a % 256, b / 256, b % 256)
      end
    end
  end
}
\catcode`\%=14
```

Also, use new `toutf16` function by editing `cwebmac.tex` like this:

```
--- /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/cweb/cwebmac.tex
+++ /usr/local/cwebmac.tex
@@ -474,7 +474,7 @@
     \pdfoutline goto name {NOS} count -\secno {\outsecname}
     \def\X##1:##2\X{\Xpdf##1:##2\X \firstsecno##1.%
       {\toksF={}\makeoutlinetoks##2\outlinedone\outlinedone}%
-      \pdfoutline goto num \the\toksA \expandafter{\the\toksE}}
+      \pdfoutline goto num \the\toksA {\directlua{toutf16("\luaescapestring{\the\toksE}")}}}
   \else\ifpdf
     \special{pdf: outline -1 << /Title (\outsecname)
       /Dest [ @thispage /FitH @ypos ] >>}
@@ -491,7 +491,7 @@
   \expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname{\the\countA}}
 \def\writebookmarkline#1#2#3#4#5{{%
   \let\(=\let \let\)=\let \let\[=\let \let\]=\let \let\/=\let
-  \pdfoutline goto num #3 count -\expnumber{chunk#2.#3} {#5}}}
+  \pdfoutline goto num #3 count -\expnumber{chunk#2.#3} {\directlua{toutf16("\luaescapestring{#5}")}}}}
 \def\con{\par\vfill\eject % finish the section names
 % \ifodd\pageno\else\titletrue\null\vfill\eject\fi % for duplex printers
   \rightskip 0pt \hyphenpenalty 50 \tolerance 200
```

For the most part, bookmarks are correct (BTW, what for is that `\expandafter` in the first change?). But in this outline

[image]

there are extra backslashes before `(` and `)`. Why do they appear? Did I use the correct approach for encoding PDF outlines?

By using the above lua block in separate file with the following code, we show that `toutf16` function works correctly (i.e., it does not produce the backslashes):

```
% ...
\pdfdest num 1 fit
\pdfoutline goto num 1 count 0 {\directlua{toutf16("\luaescapestring{Если файл дан, пробовать открыть *(++argv); continue если неудача}")}}

\bye
```

In contrast, when we do everything via `\special{pdf:tounicode UTF8-UCS2}` in `dvipdfmx` by adding this to the top of `cwebmac.tex`, everything works smoothly:

```
\let\oldshipout\shipout
\def\shipout{\global\let\shipout\oldshipout\afterassignment\myboat\setbox255=}
\def\myboat{\aftergroup\myship}
\def\myship{\setbox255=\vbox{\special{pdf:tounicode UTF8-UCS2}\unvbox255}\shipout\box255}
\let\pdf+
```

**EDIT** for more info and better solution see [this](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2016-February/022170.html) thread.

Comment: Let me guess: the pdf uses a different font format than the dvi viewer?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: if you try to compile any cweb file (ASCII-only) with pdftex, you will see what I'm talking about... DVI viewer is irrelevant here, I'm using the same pdf viewer in both cases - I convert `dvi` to `pdf` with `dvipdfmx`.

Answer (score 2):

`toutf16` function should be changed to this:

```
\directlua{
  function toutf16(str)
    tex.write(string.char(92) .. "376" .. string.char(92) .. "377")
    for c in string.utfvalues(str) do
      if c < 0x10000 then
        tex.write(string.char(92) .. string.format("%03o", c / 256) ..
                  string.char(92) .. string.format("%03o", c % 256))
      else
        c = c - 0x10000
        local c1 = c / 1024 + 0xD800
        local c2 = c % 1024 + 0xDC00
        tex.write(string.char(92) .. string.format("%03o", c1 / 256) ..
                  string.char(92) .. string.format("%03o", c1 % 256) ..
                  string.char(92) .. string.format("%03o", c2 / 256) ..
                  string.char(92) .. string.format("%03o", c2 % 256))
      end
    end
  end
}
```

Also, `cwebmac.tex` must instead be changed like this:

```
...
\pdfoutline goto name {NOS} count -\secno {\directlua{toutf16("\outsecname")}}
...
\pdfoutline goto num \the\toksA {\directlua{toutf16(string.gsub([[\the\toksE]],string.char(92),""))}}}
...
\pdfoutline goto num #3 count -\expnumber{chunk#2.#3} {\directlua{toutf16(string.gsub([[#5]],string.char(92),""))}}}}
...
```

Besides, there are two bugs in `cwebmac.tex`, which show up when it is used in pdf mode. Following are the fixes for both of them.

1) this adds extra space after each section number:

```
--- /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/cweb/cwebmac.tex
+++ cwebmac.tex
@@ -278,7 +278,7 @@
   \sfcode`;=1500 \pretolerance 200 \hyphenpenalty 50 \exhyphenpenalty 50
   \noindent{\let\*=\lapstar\bf\secstar.\quad}%
   \ifpdftex\smash{\raise\baselineskip\hbox to0pt{%
-     \let\*=\empty\pdfdest num \secstar fith}}
+     \let\*=\empty\pdfdest num \secstar fith}}%
   \else\ifpdf\smash{\raise\baselineskip\hbox to0pt{%
      \let\*=\empty\special{%
        pdf: dest (\romannumeral\secstar) [ @thispage /FitH @ypos ]}}}\fi\fi}
```

2) this removes all the bookmarks, if `\nosecs` is used:

```
--- /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/cweb/cwebmac.tex
+++ cwebmac.tex
@@ -457,6 +457,7 @@
 \def\fin{\par\vfill\eject % this is done when we are ending the index
   \ifpagesaved\null\vfill\eject\fi % output a null index column
   \if L\lr\else\null\vfill\eject\fi % finish the current page
+  \ifpdftex \makebookmarks \fi
   \parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil
   \def\grouptitle{NAMES OF THE SECTIONS}
   \let\topsecno=\nullsec
@@ -470,7 +471,7 @@
   \def\Us{\note{Used in sections}} % crossref for uses of a section
   \def\I{\par\hangindent 2em}\let\*=*
   \ifacro \def\outsecname{Names of the sections} \let\Xpdf\X
-  \ifpdftex \makebookmarks \pdfdest name {NOS} fitb
+  \ifpdftex \pdfdest name {NOS} fitb
     \pdfoutline goto name {NOS} count -\secno {\outsecname}
     \def\X##1:##2\X{\Xpdf##1:##2\X \firstsecno##1.%
       {\toksF={}\makeoutlinetoks##2\outlinedone\outlinedone}%
```